# Filesystem device on a VPS

Tags: linux, data-recovery, vps, rm

I did some bullcrap on my VPS and accidentaly deleted wrong files. Now I want to recover them with extundelete but I can't seem to find the filesystem device on my VPS. I tried `ls -la /dev | grep ^b` so that it returned only devices with the block attribute and I got this :
`br-x------  1 root root 144,  68 Sep 28 23:12 simfs` (I was root when doing this)
So I launched (still as root) `extundelete --restore-all /dev/simfs`, but then I get this :
`extundelete: failed to read-only open device "/dev/simfs": Error code 1`

Is `/dev/simfs` really what I'm looking for ?
Here's a complete `ls -la /dev` :
`total 4
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root     1380 Sep 28 23:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root     4096 Oct 13 08:18 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root       60 Sep 28 23:12 .udev
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root      500 Sep 28 23:12 char
crw-------  1 root root   5,   1 Sep 28 23:12 console
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       13 Sep 28 23:12 fd -> /proc/self/fd
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root   1,   7 Sep 28 23:12 full
crw-------  1 root root  10, 229 Sep 28 23:12 fuse
crw-------  1 root root   1,  11 Sep 28 23:12 kmsg
srw-rw-rw-  1 root root        0 Sep 28 23:12 log
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       60 Sep 28 23:12 net
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root   1,   3 Sep 28 23:12 null
crw-rw-rwT  1 root root   5,   2 Oct 15 20:31 ptmx
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root        0 Sep 28 23:12 pts
crw-r--r--  1 root root   2,   0 Sep 28 23:12 ptyp0
crw-r--r--  1 root root   2,   1 Sep 28 23:12 ptyp1
crw-r--r--  1 root root   2,   2 Sep 28 23:12 ptyp2
crw-r--r--  1 root root   2,   3 Sep 28 23:12 ptyp3
crw-r--r--  1 root root   2,   4 Sep 28 23:12 ptyp4
crw-r--r--  1 root root   2,   5 Sep 28 23:12 ptyp5
crw-r--r--  1 root root   2,   6 Sep 28 23:12 ptyp6
crw-r--r--  1 root root   2,   7 Sep 28 23:12 ptyp7
crw-r--r--  1 root root   2,   8 Sep 28 23:12 ptyp8
crw-r--r--  1 root root   2,   9 Sep 28 23:12 ptyp9
crw-r--r--  1 root root   2,  10 Sep 28 23:12 ptypa
crw-r--r--  1 root root   2,  11 Sep 28 23:12 ptypb
crw-r--r--  1 root root   2,  12 Sep 28 23:12 ptypc
crw-r--r--  1 root root   2,  13 Sep 28 23:12 ptypd
crw-r--r--  1 root root   2,  14 Sep 28 23:12 ptype
crw-r--r--  1 root root   2,  15 Sep 28 23:12 ptypf
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root   1,   8 Sep 28 23:12 random
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        8 Sep 28 23:12 shm -> /run/shm
br-x------  1 root root 144,  68 Sep 28 23:12 simfs
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       15 Sep 28 23:12 stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       15 Sep 28 23:12 stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       15 Sep 28 23:12 stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
crw-rw-rwT  1 root root   5,   0 Oct 15 20:00 tty
crw-------  1 root root   4,   0 Sep 28 23:12 tty0
crw-------  1 root root   4,   1 Sep 28 23:12 tty1
crw-------  1 root root   4,  10 Sep 28 23:12 tty10
crw-------  1 root root   4,  11 Sep 28 23:12 tty11
crw-------  1 root root   4,  12 Sep 28 23:12 tty12
crw-------  1 root root   4,   2 Sep 28 23:12 tty2
crw-------  1 root root   4,   3 Sep 28 23:12 tty3
crw-------  1 root root   4,   4 Sep 28 23:12 tty4
crw-------  1 root root   4,   5 Sep 28 23:12 tty5
crw-------  1 root root   4,   6 Sep 28 23:12 tty6
crw-------  1 root root   4,   7 Sep 28 23:12 tty7
crw-------  1 root root   4,   8 Sep 28 23:12 tty8
crw-------  1 root root   4,   9 Sep 28 23:12 tty9
crw-r--r--  1 root root   3,   0 Sep 28 23:12 ttyp0
crw-r--r--  1 root root   3,   1 Sep 28 23:12 ttyp1
crw-r--r--  1 root root   3,   2 Sep 28 23:12 ttyp2
crw-r--r--  1 root root   3,   3 Sep 28 23:12 ttyp3
crw-r--r--  1 root root   3,   4 Sep 28 23:12 ttyp4
crw-r--r--  1 root root   3,   5 Sep 28 23:12 ttyp5
crw-r--r--  1 root root   3,   6 Sep 28 23:12 ttyp6
crw-r--r--  1 root root   3,   7 Sep 28 23:12 ttyp7
crw-r--r--  1 root root   3,   8 Sep 28 23:12 ttyp8
crw-r--r--  1 root root   3,   9 Sep 28 23:12 ttyp9
crw-r--r--  1 root root   3,  10 Sep 28 23:12 ttypa
crw-r--r--  1 root root   3,  11 Sep 28 23:12 ttypb
crw-r--r--  1 root root   3,  12 Sep 28 23:12 ttypc
crw-r--r--  1 root root   3,  13 Sep 28 23:12 ttypd
crw-r--r--  1 root root   3,  14 Sep 28 23:12 ttype
crw-r--r--  1 root root   3,  15 Sep 28 23:12 ttypf
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root   1,   9 Sep 28 23:12 urandom
prw-r-----  1 root adm         0 Oct 11 08:12 xconsole
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root   1,   5 Sep 28 23:12 zero`

EDIT:
I just noticed a line :
`crw-rw-rwT 1 root root 5, 2 Oct 15 20:31 ptmx`
This is the most recently accessed file, isn't it ? Could it be the filesystem device ? And btw what are those attributes ?

Comment: Try running `mount` as root.  It should tell you what device is mounted.  Are you sure that you're going to be able to run `extundelete` on a mounted partition?  [This thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/extundelete/mailman/extundelete-users/thread/4FA5335C.1080909@otq.za.net/) says that its probably not wise to try.

Comment: The only interesting lines `mount` returned are  
`/var/lib/vz/private/2167 on / type simfs (rw,relatime,usrquota,grpquota) |  
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime) |  
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)`  
So I guess what I'm looking for is the partition mounted on `/var/lib/vz/private/2167`, but what is the device file then ?
And thank you for the `extundelete` thread, I wasn't aware of that. Should I unmount the partition before then ? Will I be stil able to access the device file if one ever exists ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using an OpenVZ container. It's not a real VPS; it does not have emulated hardware of its own, it doesn't even have a real disk, and the `/dev/simfs` is merely for show – all containers run out of plain directories on the host computer's filesystem. Therefore direct block access won't be possible.

As for `ptmx`, it has nothing to do with this – it's a *character* device (as the `c` shows), so it cannot actually hold data. "ptmx" stands for "pseudo-terminal multiplexer", the device used to create new terminal windows or accept ssh connections.

Comment: So if I understand, the "main" partition is mounted on `/` and there's no device file for it ? What are the partitions mounted on `/proc` and `/sys` ? (see the `mount` output on the above comments)

Comment: @qreon: None. `/proc` and `/sys` are _always_ virtual filesystems, generated entirely by the kernel.